# MINGW64 git stuck in console

Tags: git, github, console, mingw-w64

Hello Im practicing git and currently I stuck at this screen I dont know 
how to get out I tried everything ESC and :x and :q
nothing works

[IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/1zn0aia.png[/IMG]

Comment: Yeah....This is called a terminal :D

Comment: Ok I understand but how do I get to part where I type my git commands the part where line starts with $

Comment: Hit `STRG + C` to get out of this

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue myself when I commit without a message. Just type

```
:quit!
```

And it should bail you out.